# Finding estimator of $B$ without $A$

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Consider the model $$y_i = Bx_i + \epsilon_i$$

where $\epsilon_1, \ldots , \epsilon_n$ are independent and identically distributed as normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I know that if the model was $y_i = A + Bx_i + \epsilon_i$ I would have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\epsilon_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - A - Bx_i)^2 $$

And then I would find the partial derivatives of $A$ and $B$ and set them equal to $0$ so I can find their estimators.

How is this done when there is no $A$??

Answer (score 1):

Similar method would apply.

You would minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^n ( y_i - Bx_i)^2$$

Find the partial derivative of the function with respect to $B$ and then set them to $0$ so that you can find the estimator.